# How to make my dashboard accessible only for admin and seller in laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, admin, middleware

`DashboardController.php`

```php
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    // codes.....

}
```

> Initially, I make a middlewire for any auth user to access this **dashboard**.

**Goal:** I want to make this `dashboard` for only `admin` and `seller`. So that normal user can not access dashboard route.

**How to do that?**

**Reference table**

`users` table

```php
         Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('photo')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->longText('cartitems')->nullable();
            $table->longText('wishlist')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('discount')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> This is `users` table.

`roles` table

```php
       Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('display_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> This is `roles` table. And every user have a role such as `Superadmin`, `admin`, `seller` or`customer`

`role_user` table

```php
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> In this pivot table make a relationship between `users` and `roles` table.

**I HAVE TRIED THESE STEPS**

`DashboardController.php`

```php
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

`Kernel.php`

```php
   'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
```

`Admin.php` [new Middlewire]

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    dd(Auth::user());
}
```

> But this `Admin.php` can't not access the current authenticated user.

> it shows **null**

Comment: are you using any role permission package or you built it on your own??

Comment: No I am not using any package. Only laravel auth package i am using. And building from scratch.

Comment: then you can make some middleware based on roles and use them on routes.

Comment: ```php public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role->name == 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return Redirect::route('dashboard.index');

        // return $next($request);
    }```.... trying ... but error....

Comment: which error? and please include this code in your question?

Comment: I have added what I have tried.... Please have a look.... bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `auth()->user()` in a middleware you need to use load the `auth` middleware before. There are several ways to do that, including directly giving the routes a middleware using route groups. Otherwise, Laravel will not recognize that there is a logged-in user.

In case you don't want to do that there is another way that is slightly crude but it does the job equally well since you are writing your own roles logic. You can create a helper function `hasRole()` that does the same thing and use it in your controllers.

Edit: This is something I did for permissions rather than roles but I think it might help:

```
if(!function_exists('hasPermission')){
    function hasPermission($permissionName){
        if(auth()->check()) {

            $user = \App\Admin::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->with('role.permissions')->first();
            $permission = \App\AdminPermissions::where('name', $permissionName)->first();
            return response()->json($user->role->permissions->contains($permission));

        } else {

            return 'Unauthenticated';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use that 'hasRole()'? Will you please help me out. Is this should write in User model for relationship?

Comment: @ImrulHasan I normally create a file called ```helpers.php``` and include all my helper functions in it. I then include it in the composer autoload array and can use it everywhere. As for the hasRole($role) function itself, it basically does ```auth()->check()``` and then using the role relation with the user model it checks if this user has this role.

Comment: if you give me some reference link for that. It would be helpful. I have lack of knowledge on it.

Comment: @ImrulHasan if you want i made a document for the helper functions and have a code for roles.

Comment: @ImrulHasan this is a link to help with the helper functions. I will add the code for the hasRole to my answer
https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers

Answer (score 0):

I have done with a similar way. But I didn't face any problem.

If you put everything on the exact position it should work.